# how to use celeryd.conf file provided in production

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

This is the file provided at https://github.com/ask/django-celery/blob/master/contrib/supervisord/celeryd.conf . How can I run this conf file ?

I am running my django app using gunicorn

```
; =======================================
;  celeryd supervisor example for Django
; =======================================

[program:celery]
command=/path/to/project/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO
directory=/path/to/project
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That configuration file can't be run on its own; it is for use with [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

You need to install supervisord (if you have pip, use `pip install supervisor`), [create a configuration file for it](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#creating-a-configuration-file) using `sudo echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf` and then copy paste the contents of the file above into your supervisord configuration file as described in the supervisord documentation under [Adding a program](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program).

So basically run the following at your shell:

```
pip install supervisor
sudo echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
sudo wget -O - -o /dev/null https://raw.github.com/ask/django-celery/master/contrib/supervisord/celeryd.conf >> /etc/supervisor.conf
sudo $EDITOR /etc/supervisor.conf
```

and edit the config file to your heart's content.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gunicorn, but it seems to be a server like any other. Celery & Supervisor aren't related to Gunicorn, so my answer should still apply. OTOH, if you want to [monitor Gunicorn with Supervisor](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html#supervisor), the gunicorn docs tell you how to do that. Am I missing something?